# Mqtt-spy not opening

Tags: server, java

i'm trying to install mqtt-spy but it just doesn't open. I have installed java8 and java9, and when i use command:

```
java -jar mqtt-spy-0.5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

this is the output i get:

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:68)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

And that's it, nothing happens. I'm pretty much newbie on Ubuntu so i just don't know what can be the cause.

Comment: Are you running this over a ssh console on a remote server? Does it work when you add `-X` (like `ssh -X <rest-of-the-options>`) to your `ssh` call?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue too. When I run this, the UI never shows up

```
java -jar mqtt-spy-0.6.0-beta-b52-jar-with-dependencies.jar

2017-03-28 13:07:46,369 DEBUG [MqttViewManager               ]  - Selected perspective = DEFAULT
2017-03-28 13:07:47,461 INFO  [MqttViewManager               ]  - Default configuration file present (/Users/v506616/mqtt-spy/mqtt-spy-configuration.xml) = false
2017-03-28 13:07:47,462 DEBUG [BaseConfigurationManager      ]  - Creating root group called 'All connections'
2017-03-28 13:07:53,280 DEBUG [ControlPanelController        ]  - Retrieved version info = pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.SpyVersions@7df7be89[releaseStatuses=pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.ReleaseStatuses@6b7b57e7[releaseStatus={pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.ReleaseStatus@7c7469d5[fromVersion=0.5.1-42, toVersion=0.5.1-42, updateTitle=Bugs have been found in this release!, updateDetails=Best to update to version 0.5.4 (build 52)., updateStatus=CRITICAL],pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.ReleaseStatus@7f11b17f[fromVersion=0.5.1-44, toVersion=0.5.1-44, updateTitle=Bugs have been found in this release!, updateDetails=Best to update to version 0.5.4 (build 52)., updateStatus=CRITICAL],pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.ReleaseStatus@3f525be2[fromVersion=0.5.2-46, toVersion=0.5.3-50, updateTitle=Almost there!, updateDetails=Download version 0.5.4 (build 52) and get the edge again!, updateStatus=UPDATE_RECOMMENDED],pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.ReleaseStatus@e27e780[fromVersion=0.5.4-52, toVersion=0.5.4-52, updateTitle=Living on the edge!, updateDetails=You're on the latest release - [version]., updateStatus=ON_LATEST],pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.ReleaseStatus@51421d50[fromVersion=0.6.0-beta-26, toVersion=0.6.0-beta-51, updateTitle=Living in the stone age!, updateDetails=There is a new experimental release - 0.6.0 beta (build 52)., updateStatus=UPDATE_RECOMMENDED],pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.ReleaseStatus@23aac44e[fromVersion=0.6.0-beta-52, toVersion=0.6.0-beta-99, updateTitle=Living on the edge!, updateDetails=You're on an experimental beta release - [version]., updateStatus=ON_LATEST]}], latestReleases=pl.baczkowicz.spy.ui.generated.versions.LatestReleases@e0a0692[latestRelease=<null>]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both `mqtt-spy-0.5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar` and `mqtt-spy-1.0.0.jar`.

They start normally after installation of `openjfx` package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with OpenJDK 1.8.0_131. Installation of JavaFX is recommended on [wiki-page](https://github.com/kamilfb/mqtt-spy/wiki/GettingStarted#introduction).